# SendKeys::Send, going berserk

Tags: .net, c++-cli, infinite-loop, freeze, sendkeys

I am trying to make updates to two linked `TextBox`es. I disable events in one and then send keystrokes using eg `SendKeys::Send("A");` having first given it focus:

```
texBox2->Focus();
texBox2->KeyDown -= gcnew KeyEventHandler(this, &Form1::texBox2_KeyDown);
SendKeys::Send("A");
texBox2->KeyDown += gcnew KeyEventHandler(this, &Form1::texBox2_KeyDown);
```

It *almost* works but goes totally mental instead repeating the character (I daren't look to check which exact key because I'm frantically firefighting an overflow) until I press control-alt-del. No other keys have any effect and the mouse freezes up. But task manager miraculously restores my control, I don't stop or kill anything from it.

Can anyone advise? The debugger hangs on that `SendKeys::Send("A");` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SendKeys` places input in the message queue which is queued and so will get processed *after* you have reconnected the events. Hence the wackiness.

My advice is to stop using `SendKeys` to update the contents of your own controls. Simply modify the contents of the text boxes directly.

Comment: Direct modification of large immutable strings causes flicker, I have found the SendWait method more promising. I had set a break point in each handler and it wasn't breaking to them while in the 'infinite' loop.

Comment: Assuming this is WinForms then you can append characters cheaply with the windows api using WM_SETSEL I think. There may be a .net way to do it. Reassigning the whole string is bad but SendKeys is worse. Use WM_SETSEL is my top tip here.

Comment: But how right you are. Even more wackiness after initial satisfaction with SendWait. The whole screen (not just textboxes) flicker and if I hold a key down it appears out of place as I'm updating the second programmatically. No massive loops though :) Thanks for the WM_SETSEL tip David

Comment: actually EM_SETSEL and EM_REPLACESEL are the messages.