# How to translate KeyCode to work at Keys.SendKey

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys

is there a way to Translate a KeyCode in that way ,which will work if i use it at Keys.Sendkey();

```
private void Manager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      Keys.SendKey(e.KeyCode.toString());
}
```

i tried that way and it wont work ,so is there a way to do that dynamically.

Comment: It's really a shame there is no pre-made converter for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i don't know a better what but this ,you should capture all keys on KeyDown event and send them as String in that format from that web site.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Keys is the enumeration and does not contain a SendKey method.  You can however do something like this:

```
SendKeys.Send(Keys.A.ToString());
```

You can also send multiple keys by using string concatenation:

```
SendKeys.Send(Keys.A.ToString() + Keys.B.ToString());
```

Similary, this code works for me:

```
private void departmentList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Keys key = e.KeyCode;
    SendKeys.Send(key.ToString());
}
```

Also check out this question: [SendKeys::Send, going berserk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718220/sendkeyssend-going-berserk).  What is your goal by doing this, if I might ask?

Comment: using you're method wont work for Special Key's like Enter ,Escape etc. it work's only for random keys Letter and Number's. My goal is to send these Key's at a WebService than another Portion of Application will get these key's and Send the System where is being running by.

Comment: ToString() convert Number 1 to `D1` not `1` and this will sends `D` and `1` sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

It works great!

```
    public string ToString(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.Back:
                return "{BACKSPACE}";
            case Keys.Separator:
                return "{BREAK}";
            case Keys.CapsLock:
                return "{CAPSLOCK}";
            case Keys.Delete:
                return "{DELETE}";
            case Keys.Down:
                return "{DOWN}";
            case Keys.End:
                return "{END}";
            case Keys.Enter:
                return "{ENTER}";
            case Keys.Escape:
                return "{ESC}";
            case Keys.Help:
                return "{HELP}";
            case Keys.Home:
                return "{HOME}";
            case Keys.Insert:
                return "{INSERT}";
            case Keys.Left:
                return "{LEFT}";
            case Keys.NumLock:
                return "{NUMLOCK}";
            case Keys.PageDown:
                return "{PGDN}";
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return "{PGUP}";
            case Keys.PrintScreen:
                return "{PRTSC}";
            case Keys.Right:
                return "{RIGHT}";
            case Keys.Scroll:
                return "{SCROLLLOCK}";
            case Keys.Tab:
                return "{TAB}";
            case Keys.Up:
                return "{UP}";
            case Keys.F1:
                return "{F1}";
            case Keys.F2:
                return "{F2}";
            case Keys.F3:
                return "{F3}";
            case Keys.F4:
                return "{F4}";
            case Keys.F5:
                return "{F5}";
            case Keys.F6:
                return "{F6}";
            case Keys.F7:
                return "{F7}";
            case Keys.F8:
                return "{F8}";
            case Keys.F9:
                return "{F9}";
            case Keys.F10:
                return "{F10}";
            case Keys.F11:
                return "{F11}";
            case Keys.F12:
                return "{F12}";
            case Keys.F13:
                return "{F13}";
            case Keys.F14:
                return "{F14}";
            case Keys.F15:
                return "{F15}";
            case Keys.F16:
                return "{F16}";
            case Keys.Add:
                return "{ADD}";
            case Keys.Subtract:
                return "{SUBTRACT}";
            case Keys.Multiply:
                return "{MULTIPLY}";
            case Keys.Divide:
                return "{DIVIDE}";
            case Keys.ShiftKey:
                return "+";
            case Keys.ControlKey:
                return "^";
            case Keys.Alt:
                return "%";

        }
        return key.ToString();
    }
```

Enjoy...