# How to send special keys to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with Textbox to convert characters. I needed to press 'Oem3(192 in keys enum)' key automatically. I tried sendkeys(), but I cannot find that key. What can I do to send that key to textbox?
Codes I tried:

```
sendkeys.send({OEM3});  //error
sendkeys.send(keys.Oem3);  //just entering '192' into textbox
sendkeys.send({192});  //error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate KeyCode to work at Keys.SendKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095475/) and [C# SendKeys.Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012616/) and [Sending Windows key using SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366152/)

Comment: Last maintained fork: https://github.com/GregsStack/InputSimulatorStandard